# number of fields in select in Cassandra will take less time

Tags: cassandra, cql

Will it take less time if I select comparatively less field from Cassandra ?

For example:

```
1) select a, b, c, d, e from table where some condition

2) select a, b, c from table where some condition
```

Will 2nd query take less time as compare to your first query ? Both are having same where condition but different number of fields to select

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't make that much of a difference.

Most of the customers I work with have a SLA of 6-8 milliseconds so you're not really going to save anything significant. Cheers!

Comment: if difference in select fields dropped down from 30 to 4 with same where clause condition. then ?